# How to use CONCAT function in Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

How can I use the CONCAT function in a Laravel query?

```php
$checkLogin = User::where(['Username' => $_POST['id'], 'Password' => $_POST['pass']])
    ->first();
```

I want to concatenate username.

```php
CONCAT(Username, '#', LPAD(NameID, 4, '0'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DB::raw()` to `CONCAT`. And you can use `Request` instead.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function YourFunction(Request $data)
{
    $checkLogin = User::query()
        ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(Username, '#', LPAD(NameID, 4, '0'))"), $data->id)
        ->where('Password', $data->pass)
        ->first();
}
```

Make sure you put this at the top: `use DB;`

Comment: and ```$_POST['id']``` where i put dude? Because this need on Username.

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `whereRaw($condition, $bindings)`, which lets you use whatever SQL you want:

```
$checkLogin = User::query()
    ->whereRaw("CONCAT(Username, '#', LPAD(NameID, 4, '0')) = ?", [$_POST['id']])
    ->where('Password', $_POST['pass'])
    ->first();
```

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

Comment: @SnapKWI I fixed it in my answer. Sorry, forgot to swap it.